# Index exceeds matrix dimensions error in matlab database

Tags: database, matlab, user-interface, import

i have database named 'data' , in gui i have 3 editbox which are name,gpa,salary and a push button . have data in database like this :

```
field= {'name','gpa','salary'}
newdata = {'Andre',3.2,$1000}
```

my program like this :

```
conn = database('db1_mysql','root','');
sql = ['select * from data where name =','''',handles.name,''''];
data = fetch(conn,sql)
handles.data = data;
guidata(hObject,handles)
if isempty(data)
  msgbox('data not found')
  set(handles.gpa,'String','')
  set(handles.salary,'String','')
else
  set(handles.gpa,'String',data(1,2))
  set(handles.salary,'String',data(1,3))
end
```

what i want is if i type Andre in name editbox in gui , his gpa and salary show up in others edit box . but i'm getting error : Index exceeds matrix dimensions. my database have 1 row , and 3 coloumn . how can it not working. Im using matlab R2016a

Comment: What does `data` look like if you call `disp(data)`

Comment: if i type andre in editbox result is --- name: {'Andre'},
gpa : 3.2000,
salary: $1000

Comment: So is it a `struct`? Check with `class(data)`

Comment: maybe , do you have suggestion sir to correct it ?, im stuck and confuse why it's not working

Comment: yes sir i have checked , it's struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `fetch` in your case is going to be a struct, therefore to access the individual elements you need to use [dot referencing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html) instead of `()` indexing.

```
set(handles.gpa, 'String', data.gpa)
set(handles.salary, 'String', data.salary)
```

If you want to show salary as a whole number you can convert it using `num2str`

```
set(handles.salary, 'String', num2str(data.salary, '%d'))
```

Comment: Thank you, it work very well !!!. 1 more thing sir, if salary show like this '1e+06' how to fix that ? thanks a lot before

Comment: @AlfiNugraha Updated

Comment: sir, would you like to  help me solving this problem please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488338/reference-to-non-existent-field-error-when-showing-database-data-to-editbox-in-g . Thanks b4